# QGIS 2.2: GDAL Grid (Interpolation) Error

Tags: qgis, dem, xyz, hgt

As much as i understand Raster -> Analysis -> Raster (Interpolation) can provide me with a terrain file out of a shape file with a Z coordinate.
I select the input and output file and a Z field.
It gives me this error:
ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.

Unable to create target dataset "D:/shp/terrain.dem". 
GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.

Tried some other formats (I'm aiming for either .dem, .hgt or .xyz) but got the same error everytime. What am I missing here?

The Vector layer contains X coord, Y coord, Z coord, number and name fields.

Comment: After some playing i thought it somehow magically let me do all those formats i needed but they were unusable by other piece of software that i needed those formats for (gave me errors etc.) then i noticed that whatever format i chose as an output format, the comand line at the bottom said this : `gdal_grid -zfield ZEMES_H -l sujungtisukoordinatem -of GTiff "D:\\shp\\terrain.shp" "D:/shp/XYZZ"`

Comment: which means it still did Geotiff/tiff and the files produced had no extensions. Is this plugin just buggy in general? And is there an easy way of achieving what i originaly wanted to achieve: converting a shapefile with x,y,z coord to .dem, .hgt or .xyz?

Answer (score 2):

This does seem to be related an existing QGIS bug report http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4304

You could try using gdalinfo to find the list of supported formats like:

```
gdalinfo --formats
```

Which on this PC gives me:

```
Supported Formats:
  VRT (rw+v): Virtual Raster
  GTiff (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
  NITF (rw+vs): National Imagery Transmission Format
  RPFTOC (rovs): Raster Product Format TOC format
  ECRGTOC (rovs): ECRG TOC format
  HFA (rw+v): Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
  SAR_CEOS (rov): CEOS SAR Image
  CEOS (rov): CEOS Image
  JAXAPALSAR (rov): JAXA PALSAR Product Reader (Level 1.1/1.5)
  GFF (rov): Ground-based SAR Applications Testbed File Format (.gff)
  ELAS (rw+v): ELAS
  AIG (rov): Arc/Info Binary Grid
  AAIGrid (rwv): Arc/Info ASCII Grid
  GRASSASCIIGrid (rov): GRASS ASCII Grid
  SDTS (rov): SDTS Raster
  DTED (rwv): DTED Elevation Raster
  PNG (rwv): Portable Network Graphics
  JPEG (rwv): JPEG JFIF
  MEM (rw+): In Memory Raster
  JDEM (rov): Japanese DEM (.mem)
  GIF (rwv): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
  BIGGIF (rov): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
  ESAT (rov): Envisat Image Format
  BSB (rov): Maptech BSB Nautical Charts
  XPM (rwv): X11 PixMap Format
  BMP (rw+v): MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
  DIMAP (rov): SPOT DIMAP
  AirSAR (ro): AirSAR Polarimetric Image
  RS2 (ros): RadarSat 2 XML Product
  PCIDSK (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
  PCRaster (rw): PCRaster Raster File
  ILWIS (rw+v): ILWIS Raster Map
  SGI (rw+): SGI Image File Format 1.0
  SRTMHGT (rwv): SRTMHGT File Format
  Leveller (rw+): Leveller heightfield
  Terragen (rw+): Terragen heightfield
  GMT (rw): GMT NetCDF Grid Format
  netCDF (rw+s): Network Common Data Format
  HDF4 (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
  HDF4Image (rw+): HDF4 Dataset
  ISIS3 (rov): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 3)
  ISIS2 (rw+v): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
  PDS (rov): NASA Planetary Data System
  TIL (rov): EarthWatch .TIL
  ERS (rw+v): ERMapper .ers Labelled
  JPEG2000 (rwv): JPEG-2000 part 1 (ISO/IEC 15444-1)
  L1B (rov): NOAA Polar Orbiter Level 1b Data Set
  FIT (rwv): FIT Image
  GRIB (rov): GRIdded Binary (.grb)
  RMF (rw+v): Raster Matrix Format
  WCS (rovs): OGC Web Coverage Service
  WMS (rwvs): OGC Web Map Service
  MSGN (ro): EUMETSAT Archive native (.nat)
  RST (rw+v): Idrisi Raster A.1
  INGR (rw+v): Intergraph Raster
  GSAG (rwv): Golden Software ASCII Grid (.grd)
  GSBG (rw+v): Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
  GS7BG (rw+v): Golden Software 7 Binary Grid (.grd)
  COSAR (ro): COSAR Annotated Binary Matrix (TerraSAR-X)
  TSX (rov): TerraSAR-X Product
  COASP (ro): DRDC COASP SAR Processor Raster
  R (rwv): R Object Data Store
  MAP (rov): OziExplorer .MAP
  PNM (rw+v): Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
  DOQ1 (rov): USGS DOQ (Old Style)
  DOQ2 (rov): USGS DOQ (New Style)
  ENVI (rw+v): ENVI .hdr Labelled
  EHdr (rw+v): ESRI .hdr Labelled
  GenBin (rov): Generic Binary (.hdr Labelled)
  PAux (rw+): PCI .aux Labelled
  MFF (rw+): Vexcel MFF Raster
  MFF2 (rw+): Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
  FujiBAS (ro): Fuji BAS Scanner Image
  GSC (rov): GSC Geogrid
  FAST (rov): EOSAT FAST Format
  BT (rw+v): VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
  LAN (rw+v): Erdas .LAN/.GIS
  CPG (ro): Convair PolGASP
  IDA (rw+): Image Data and Analysis
  NDF (rov): NLAPS Data Format
  EIR (rov): Erdas Imagine Raw
  DIPEx (rov): DIPEx
  LCP (rov): FARSITE v.4 Landscape File (.lcp)
  GTX (rw+v): NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
  LOSLAS (rov): NADCON .los/.las Datum Grid Shift
  NTv2 (rw+vs): NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
  CTable2 (rw+v): CTable2 Datum Grid Shift
  ACE2 (rov): ACE2
  SNODAS (rov): Snow Data Assimilation System
  ARG (rwv): Azavea Raster Grid format
  RIK (ro): Swedish Grid RIK (.rik)
  USGSDEM (rwv): USGS Optional ASCII DEM (and CDED)
  GXF (ro): GeoSoft Grid Exchange Format
  DODS (ro): DAP 3.x servers
  HTTP (ro): HTTP Fetching Wrapper
  BAG (ro): Bathymetry Attributed Grid
  HDF5 (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
  HDF5Image (ro): HDF5 Dataset
  NWT_GRD (rov): Northwood Numeric Grid Format .grd/.tab
  NWT_GRC (rov): Northwood Classified Grid Format .grc/.tab
  ADRG (rw+vs): ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
  SRP (rov): Standard Raster Product (ASRP/USRP)
  BLX (rw): Magellan topo (.blx)
  Rasterlite (rws): Rasterlite
  EPSILON (rwv): Epsilon wavelets
  PostGISRaster (rws): PostGIS Raster driver
  SAGA (rw+v): SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
  KMLSUPEROVERLAY (rwv): Kml Super Overlay
  XYZ (rwv): ASCII Gridded XYZ
  HF2 (rwv): HF2/HFZ heightfield raster
  PDF (rwvs): Geospatial PDF
  OZI (rov): OziExplorer Image File
  CTG (rov): USGS LULC Composite Theme Grid
  E00GRID (rov): Arc/Info Export E00 GRID
  ZMap (rwv): ZMap Plus Grid
  NGSGEOID (rov): NOAA NGS Geoid Height Grids
  MBTiles (rov): MBTiles
  IRIS (rov): IRIS data (.PPI, .CAPPi etc)
```

Comment: How/where exactly do i use this gdalinfo command? And how come according to your list you can do an xyz ascii file but i can not?

Comment: In Windows open a command prompt, and type the command there.

Comment: command not recognized

Comment: Search for gdalinfo.exe on your system and run the command from that location.  If you installed QGIS using OSGeo4W64 you might find it at: C:\OSGeo4W64\bin.