# Interpolate vector layer and raster layer data into regular grid data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, topography, bathymetry

I'm new to using GIS software. I obtained two different sets of data:

1. Topography data (raster, .asc)
2. Bathymetry data (shapefile, .shp, etc)

I include topography data using `Add Raster Layer` and bathymetry data using `Add Vector Layer` in QGIS. (See attached figure) [image: QGIS with raster and vector data]

Is there any possible way to interpolate both different data sets like this? I have done some diggings, but they are mostly discussing how to interpolate vector layer data. I would like to get the water depth and land elevation in the same file after interpolation either in .xyz or .grd, so that I can use this as a computational domain for my simulation model.

Comment: You can convert your raster to points then use the GDAL grid in QGIS, this will triangulate the sparse points and interpolate to a continuous raster  -or- add some points at the far edge, use GDAL grid then insert your known raster into the interpolated raster (more fiddly but the existing raster wont change).

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Is the QGIS GDAL grid in `Raster` - `Analysis` - `Grid (Interpolation)`? In my raster, those nodes without data are set to be -9999. In this case, should I extract those nodes with land elevation (positive value) manually, like writing a simply program to do it?

Comment: -9999 sounds like NoData, if so then remove those ones... start editing, select by attributes and then delete (don't forget to save). There's about 3 different grid/interpolation tools I've found in the latest version of QGIS, I use the command line one but have a go with all 3 then pick the one that looks best; you will still have the original data and any results you don't like can be deleted then try again a different way.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson After selecting the `Grid (Interpolation)`, I opened a shapefile as the `Input file`, chose `Depth` as `Z field` and chose `.ASC` as `Output file`. There are three interpolation algorithm as you mentioned, and I picked `Nearest neighbor`. `Resize` and `Extent` were unchecked. After clicking `OK`, a message popped out saying `ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.`. I tried following this [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93469/qgis-2-2-gdal-grid-interpolation-error?rq=1), but the command prompt console disappeared.

Comment: Try creating the output as GeoTiff or ERDAS IMG then when successful convert to ASC. Some drivers don't implement Create() but rather are implemented in CreateCopy(), these two formats' drivers  *definitely* implement Create() (I've used them in C++ and know that they're there in all versions of GDAL I've worked with)